# How many ways are there to put 5 balls in 2 boxes if the balls are not distinguishable and neither are the boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

How many ways are there to put 5 balls in 2 boxes if the balls are not distinguishable and neither are the boxes?

I was thinking (5,0), (4,1), and (3,2) for a total of 12 ways. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You spelled it out correctly but was wondering why you would say 12 ways though?

Comment: /I see what you mean. How many would there be then

Answer (score 1):

It is 3: the partitions of 5 into $\leq 2 $ parts. These are pretty much just the tuples you have listed: (5), (4,1), (3,2).